# REDIS Server Configuration

Tags: redis

I am working on a migration project from Oracle to Redis, my Oracle DB size is 1 TB, can you please suggest the hardware configuration for Redis. I am planning to have a master with 2 slaves for the Redis server.

What is the best option for Redis to have high availability?
Is the master-slave architecture is fine? If yes can I have all the master and slaves on the same server? If yes what are the disadvantages will occur?

Please suggest me the best option for high availability for my Redis server.

Comment: Your data set is too large to fit into a single Redis instance. You should consider Redis Cluster. Also it should be very expensive to hold so much data in memory.

Comment: I am sorry, I have given the database size as wrong, actually, my database size is 230 GB.

Answer (score 1):

- Considering the data size you can utilize [redis cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) to store your data.
- When designed properly, this is expected to provide the high availability and partitioning your data among multiple masters in the cluster.
- To identify its suitability, you need to perform some kind of benchmarks with the real data and real queries expected from your application.
- You can use [redis-benckmark](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) utility provided by redis out of the box and simulate the expected data and calls to get a picture of what's expected